# List of items in REST interface API and ACID

Tags: rest

I'm creating REST API in which I'm going to assign some items to group:

`POST /rest/group/<group1>/item`

body

```
[
    {id: 'item1'},
    {id: 'item2'},
    {id: 'item3'},
    ...
]
```

The problem is that I need to cover following use-cases:

1. assigning items to new group
2. assigning items to existing group with already assigned items, those
   items must stay untouched
3. removing items from group - all items
4. and removing part of items
5. might be needed to combine those use cases

I don't have a possibility to use PATCH method.

What is the best option to archive this?

One that I have in mind is something like this:

```
[
    {id: 'item1', action: 'add'},
    {id: 'item2', action: 'add'},
    {id: 'item3', action: 'remove'},
    ...
]
```

I'm asking because maybe there is a more efficient solution for that purpose.

I need to archive ACID also, so don't want to send multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't really need to send actions in your body, as you have HTTP Methods that can express that.**

- First, to make your request a little more RESTful, I strongly suggest you to use `/rest/groups/<group1>/items`, because the [guidelines](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9) recommend to take resources in plural.
- **Assigning items to a new group:**

`(POST) /rest/groups/<group1>/items`

With the items inside the json body.

- **Assigning items to existing group with existing items:**

`(PUT) /rest/groups/<group1>/items`

With the new items to be added inside the json body. In your application, make sure that you recognize it's a (PUT) request, and if so, only add them to the existing list of items. The (POST) should override the entire list so you have a way to quickly change the item collection if needed.

- **Removing items from group - all items**

`(DELETE) /rest/groups/<group1>/items`

Delete the entire item collection for that group.

- **Removing part of items**

`(DELETE) /rest/groups/<group1>/items/<item1>`

Sending an entity body in a (DELETE) method is not forbidden, but it's a practice that most of the known API's tend to avoid. You should be deleting specific items by sending its ID as a path variable.

**To batch delete items, you could use query parameters like that:**

`(DELETE) /rest/groups/<group1>/items?ids=1,5,7`

That should delete the items with ID's 1, 5 and 7. Other ways of filtering the deletion can be applied as well, depending on your item model.

Comment: For the batch DELETE one could also implement [Request Batching](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch) like in the Google Drive REST API.